# Android timer,Broadcast Receiver,

Tags: android, timer, android-broadcast, android-broadcastreceiver, android-handler

Developing a timer application,

Have 4 buttons

start--Will start the timer

stop-- will stop timer

pause--will pause timer

lap time--will calculate lap time.

when button click it s working Good.

Now i am Modify the application like timer should start when phone is connected to charger and pause when phone is disconnected from charger.

The timer is starting fine when connected to the charger,

but during discharging the stop timer is not stopping at the accurate time it will be misplaced with some other time.i.e delay in minutes and seconds.

**How to make the timer pause and show correct timer when disconnected from the charger...?**

**MainActivity.java**

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.os.BatteryManager;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.SystemClock;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private static final String TAG ="Main Activity";
    TextView textView;
    Button start, pause, reset, lap;
    long MillisecondTime, StartTime, TimeBuff, UpdateTime = 0L;
    Handler handlerr;
    int Seconds, Minutes, MilliSeconds;
    ListView listView;
    String[] ListElements = new String[]{};
    List<String> ListElementsArrayList;
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
    TextView textview;
    Button button;
    IntentFilter intentfilter;
    int deviceStatus;
    String currentBatteryStatus = "Battery Info";
    int batteryLevel;
    Handler handler;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        textview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewBatteryStatus);



        intentfilter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED);
        MainActivity.this.registerReceiver(broadcastreceiver, intentfilter);



        textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
        start = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
        pause = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
        reset = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button3);
        lap = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button4) ;
        listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listview1);
        handler = new Handler() ;
        ListElementsArrayList = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(ListElements));
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                ListElementsArrayList
        );
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        start.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                StartTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
                handler.postDelayed(runnable, 0);
                reset.setEnabled(false);


            }
        });

        pause.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                TimeBuff += MillisecondTime;
                handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);
                reset.setEnabled(true);

            }
        });

        reset.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                MillisecondTime = 0L ;
                StartTime = 0L ;
                TimeBuff = 0L ;
                UpdateTime = 0L ;
                Seconds = 0 ;
                Minutes = 0 ;
                MilliSeconds = 0 ;
                textView.setText("00:00:00");

                ListElementsArrayList.clear();

                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


            }
        });

        lap.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                ListElementsArrayList.add(textView.getText().toString());
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            }
        });

    }
    public Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {

        public void run() {

            MillisecondTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() - StartTime;
            UpdateTime = TimeBuff + MillisecondTime;
            Seconds = (int) (UpdateTime / 1000);
            Minutes = Seconds / 60;
            Seconds = Seconds % 60;
            MilliSeconds = (int) (UpdateTime % 1000);
            textView.setText("" + Minutes + ":"
                    + String.format("%02d", Seconds) + ":"
                    + String.format("%03d", MilliSeconds));
            handler.postDelayed(this, 0);
        }

    };

// Broadcasts receiver//

    private BroadcastReceiver broadcastreceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

            deviceStatus = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_STATUS,-1);
            int level = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_LEVEL, -1);
            int scale = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_SCALE, -1);
            int batteryLevel=(int)(((float)level / (float)scale) * 100.0f);

            if(deviceStatus == BatteryManager.BATTERY_STATUS_CHARGING){
                StartTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
                handler.postDelayed(runnable, 0);
                reset.setEnabled(false);
                textview.setText(currentBatteryStatus+" = Charging at "+batteryLevel+" %");

            }

            if(deviceStatus == BatteryManager.BATTERY_STATUS_DISCHARGING){

                textview.setText(currentBatteryStatus+" = Discharging at "+batteryLevel+" %");

            }

            if (deviceStatus == BatteryManager.BATTERY_STATUS_FULL){

                textview.setText(currentBatteryStatus+"= Battery Full at "+batteryLevel+" %");

            }

            if(deviceStatus == BatteryManager.BATTERY_STATUS_UNKNOWN){

                textview.setText(currentBatteryStatus+" = Unknown at "+batteryLevel+" %");
            }


            if (deviceStatus == BatteryManager.BATTERY_STATUS_NOT_CHARGING){
                TimeBuff += MillisecondTime;
                handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);
                reset.setEnabled(true);
                textview.setText(currentBatteryStatus+" = Not Charging at "+batteryLevel+" %");

            }

        }
    };

}
```

**activity_main.xml**

> ```
> <TextView
>     android:text="00:00:00"
>     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>     android:id="@+id/textView"
>     android:textSize="50dp"
>     android:textStyle="bold"
>     android:textColor="#009688"
>     android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
>     android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
>
> <Button
>     android:text="Start"
>     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>     android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
>     android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
>     android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
>     android:layout_marginTop="41dp"
>     android:id="@+id/button" />
>
> <Button
>     android:text="Pause"
>     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>     android:id="@+id/button2"
>     android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/button"
>     android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button"
>     android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
>
> <Button
>     android:text="Reset"
>     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>     android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button2"
>     android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
>     android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
>     android:id="@+id/button3" />
>
> <Button
>     android:text="Save Lap"
>     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>     android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
>     android:id="@+id/button4"
>     android:layout_below="@+id/button"
>     android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
>
> <ListView
>     android:layout_width="match_parent"
>     android:layout_height="match_parent"
>     android:layout_below="@+id/button4"
>     android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
>     android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
>     android:id="@+id/listview1"/>
>
> <TextView
>     android:id="@+id/textViewBatteryStatus"
>     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>     android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/button2"
>     android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
>     android:text="Current Battery Status"
>     android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
> ```

Guidance in editing code will be helpful.

Comment: You haven't stated what is the problem you're having. "Some other time" is too general, I'm afraid. We will not be able to help if you don't investigate and say what specifically is wrong with your code. Also, most of it is not needed. Please edit so we have a [mcve].

Comment: still, your question is not clear. Try simpler sentence?

Comment: @AmitK.Saha, its edited please see

Comment: @M.Prokhorov its edited please see

Comment: The timer likely doesn't stop at discarging because you *aren't stopping it at discharging*. You stop it at `NOT_CHARGING` status. You wrote your code this way.

Comment: @M.Prokhorov   I also tried for discharging and NOT_CHARGING,but it didnt work.                                
                                                                                        
                                                       if(deviceStatus == BatteryManager.BATTERY_STATUS_NOT_CHARGING){
                TimeBuff += MillisecondTime;
                handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);

                textview.setText(currentBatteryStatus+":not Charging at "+batteryLevel+" %");

            }

Comment: "Did not work" doesn't say anything useful about your problem.

Comment: @RahulSamanta, did you try my answer?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to catch the Charger Connected and Disconnected events, then you should not use the `BATTERY_STATUS_CHARGING` and `BATTERY_STATUS_DISCHARGING` at the first place.You should listen for -

```
<receiver android:name=".YourPowerConnectionReceiver">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED"/>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_POWER_DISCONNECTED"/>
  </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Thus you will get the broadcast only during charger connected and disconnected state.

Look here : https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED